# Why would TcpListener be leaking ESTABLISHED connections?

Tags: c#, asyncsocket, tcplistener, tcp, disconnection

I have an application that's listening messages from a modem in some 30 cars. I've used TcpListener to implement server code that looks like this (error handling elided):

```
...
listener.Start()
...
void 
BeginAcceptTcpClient()
{
    if(listener.Server.IsBound) {
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(TcpClientAccepted, null);
    }
}

void 
TcpClientAccepted(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    BeginAcceptTcpClient();
    using(var client = EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)) {
    using(var stream = client.GetStream()) {
        var count   = 0;
        while((count = stream.Read(buffer, total, bufferSize - total)) > 0) {
            total += count;
        }
    }
    DoSomething(buffer)
}
```

I get the messages correctly, my problem lies with disconnections. Every 12 hours the modems get reset and get a new IP address, but the Server continues to hold the old connections active (they are marked as ESTABLISHED in tcpview). Is there any way to set a timeout for the old connections? I thought that by closing the TcpClient the TCP connection was closed (and that's what happens in my local tests), what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually a little confused by the code sample - the question *suggests* that these questions are open a reasonably long time, but the code is more typical for very short bursts; for a long-running connection, I would expect to see one of the async APIs here, not the sync API.

Sockets that die without trace are very common, especially when distributed with a number of intermediate devices that would all need to spot the shutdown. Wireless networks in particular sometimes try to keep sockets artificially alive, since it is pretty common to briefly lose a wireless connection, as the devices don't want that to kill every connection every time.

As such, it is pretty common to implement some kind of heartbeat on connections, so that you can keep track of who is still *really* alive.

As an example - I have a websocket server here, which *in theory* handles both graceful shutdowns (via a particular sequence that indicates closure), and ungraceful socket closure (unexpectedly terminating the connection) - but of the 19k connections I've seen in the last hour or so, 70 have died without hitting either of those. So instead, I track activity against a (slow) heartbeat, and kill them if they fail to respond after too long.

Re timeout; you can try the [`ReceiveTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx), but that will only help you if you aren't usually expecting big gaps in traffic.

Comment: I'm using the Async api for the connection acceptance, but the synchronous api for the reading of messages, I have messages once or twice an hour only. I don't have much control over the way the modem connect with the server (the hardware provider controls those, and couldn't explain their behavior very well). Doesn't the Dispose() of the accepted TcpClient close the connection with the client? My problem is not that the clients die on me, my problem is that they don't die when they change IPs!

Comment: @Pablo can you clarify: once a client has connected - does it send some data an immediately close? or is it open for a while?

Comment: The client connects, sends some data and...closes? That's part of the problem, I don't know. I've had connection resets (that are gracefully accepted, and the partial data received used), but the connection seems to be kept in the ESTABLISHED state always, even after I manually reset the modem (which gives it a new IP address).

Comment: @Pablo sure; but as already noted - in an unexpected closure, it is sometimes not possible to detect the broken connection; so unless you have a receive/read timeout, `Read` will block forever, and it will never close. Which is exactly what I was trying to describe. If you are expecting the data as a burst, a receive/read timeout is the easiest way to solve this; if the connection was long-lived, you'd have to use a heartbeat. So: turn on a read-timeout of, say, 5 seconds.

Comment: Aha! So you are saying, I'm getting blocked on a receive that got stuck because of a reset, but I'm not being notified of that problem! I'll test it an report back, thanks!!!

Comment: @Pablo yes, exactly that. Assuming there is no data buffered locally, `Read` can't return anything until either more data arrives or it **knows** the socket has closed. If the socket dies silently, you will never get a response from `Read`. Timeout helps with this.